# How to add a new column, based on values of two other columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have the following table (see attachment). I would like to generate SQL code, s.t. if any school started in Phase 3, the school would get a value of 1. If the school also went through either Phase 1 or 2 (or both), the value should be 0.

[image: SQL Example]

Currently, I only have the first 2 columns generated from a database. I need to include the extra column, but I have no idea how I would implement SQL code for that.

I am quite new to SQL, hence any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, learn the RDBMS you are using. Don't just tag 4 random RDBMS. Tag **only** the RDBMS you are actually using. Then show us your attempts and explain why they aren't working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       min(case when phase in ('Phase1', 'Phase2') then 0
                when phase = 'Phase3' then 1
           end) over (partition by school) as new_column
from t;
```